# having problem with while loop not registering discord.py messages in condition

Tags: python, while-loop, discord.py

so what i'm trying to do is wait for a user's input which is !accept in discord so that my betting bot can do it's work as it's kinda dumb if a user can challenge another player and the other player can't deny the challenge so what i did is

```
while msg.content != "!accept" or msg.content != "!decline":
print("not yet given")
msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == roller2 )
print("given")
```

note that i already have asked for msg from the other user/roller2 by doing

```
 msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == roller2 )
```

the reason why i know the while loop is the problem is the problem is because i found it by putting print statements in my code to see if a line works and it stops at the while loop specifically at `msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == roller2 )`

i also printed the msg.content which was given by roller2 and even if it printed out !accept or !decline the code still wouldn't get past that part and i tried commenting out the while loop and the code worked so what i want to know is why it's not seeing !accept or !decline and how do i fix this
whole code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def deathroll(ctx, user: discord.User, bet=100):
    roller1 = ctx.author.id
    roller2 = user.id
    if roller1==roller2:
        await ctx.send("you can't roll against yourself dumbass")
        return
    user2 = await client.fetch_user(roller2)
    print(user2)
    cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id = ?", (roller1,))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    connect.commit()
    print("1st")
    if len(data) == 0:
        await ctx.send("make an account first")
    cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id = ?", (roller2,))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    connect.commit()
    print("2nd")
    if len(data) == 0:
        await ctx.send("please give a user for roller2")
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == roller2 )
    cursor.execute("SELECT currency FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id=?", (roller1,))
    roller1_cash = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
    connect.commit()
    cursor.execute("SELECT currency FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id=?", (roller1,))
    roller2_cash = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
    connect.commit()
    print("3rd")
    print(msg.content)#prints out !accept or !decline when roller2 sends !accept or !decline
    while msg.content != "!accept" or msg.content != "!decline":
        print("not yet given")
        msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == roller2 )
        print("given")
    if msg.content == "decline":
        print("declined")
        return
    print("4th")#doesn't print out 4th due to while loop
    cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id = ?", (roller2,))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print("5th")
    if len(data) != 0:
        roll = 100
        while roll != 1:
            roll = random.randint(1, roll)
            await ctx.send("roller1,rolled:" + str(roll))
            if roll == 1:
                await ctx.send("the winner is roller1")
                roller1_cash = roller1_cash - bet
                roller2_cash = roller2_cash + bet
                cursor.execute("UPDATE DEATHROLL set currency=? WHERE id=?", (roller1_cash, roller1))
                connect.commit()
                cursor.execute("UPDATE DEATHROLL set currency=? WHERE id=?", (roller1_cash, roller1))
                connect.commit()
                break
            roll = random.randint(1, roll)
            await ctx.send("roller2,rolled:" + str(roll))
            if roll == 1:
                await ctx.send("the winner is roller1")
                roller1_cash = roller1_cash + bet
                roller2_cash = roller2_cash - bet
                cursor.execute("UPDATE DEATHROLL set currency=? WHERE id=?", (roller1_cash, roller1))
                connect.commit()
                cursor.execute("UPDATE DEATHROLL set currency=? WHERE id=?", (roller1_cash, roller1))
                connect.commit()
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the logic in your code in `msg.content != "!accept" or msg.content != "!decline"`.
Let's say message content is "!decline", the program would check it like that:

```py
"!decline" != "!accept" = True
"!decline" != "!decline" = False
```

Using `or` operator, returns True if one of the statements is True, so it returns True. So for this statement to be true, `msg.content` would have to be "!accept" and "!decline" at the same time. To fix this, simply use `and` instead of `or`.

Instead of the while loop, you could simply extend the check to include that the message content waited for has to be "!accept" or "!decline":

```py
msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == roller2  and m.content in ["!decline", "!accept"])
```

This could be used instead of the while loop.